# Error: exceptionjavax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: sql

```
<%           

            String ID,name,username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");   

            String leaveType, StartDate, EndDate, reason;

            leaveType = request.getParameter("leaveType");

            StartDate = request.getParameter("StartDate");

            EndDate = request.getParameter("EndDate");

            reason = request.getParameter("reason");             

           

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","12345");

                            

            ID="select EID from empinfo where EUsername="+username+"'";

            name="select EName from empinfo where EUsername="+username+"'";

            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 'leave (EID,EName,leaveType,StartDate,EndDate,Reason) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            pst.setString(1, ID);

            pst.setString(2, name);

            pst.setString(3, leaveType);

            pst.setString(4, StartDate);

            pst.setString(5, EndDate);

            pst.setString(6, reason);

           

           int row = pst.executeUpdate();           

            if(row==1)

            {

               %>

           <script>        

            alert("Leave Applied");            

        </script>

        <jsp:include page="profile.jsp"></jsp:include> 

        <% 

            }

            else

            {

                out.println("Leave Application Failed");

            }       

%>

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

root cause

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

How can solve this error?

I am new to this.
Working on my first project.

Comment: Do not use database directly in the jsp. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: You have a single quote in front of the table name `'leave`?

Comment: You can't set a subquery via parameter

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: I wrote that way because without it I was having error and it was telling that I need to add ' before the table name('leave). But thank you for all the solutions you recommended.

Comment: A ingle quout before table name is not valid

Comment: If I remove that then it gives a error  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave(EID,EName,leaveType,StartDate,EndDate,Reason) values ('4','Gara Style','Si' at line 1

Comment: Can you show the changed code please?

Comment: <%            
       try{
            String ID,name,username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");   
            String leaveType, StartDate, EndDate, reason;
            leaveType = request.getParameter("leaveType");
            StartDate = request.getParameter("StartDate");
            EndDate = request.getParameter("EndDate");
            reason = request.getParameter("reason");
                         
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Comment: Nit the whole code, only the line with the prepared statement

Comment: mysql","root","12345");
                  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                  username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");                 
                  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from empinfo where EUsername = '"+username+"'");
  while(rs.next()) {PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into leave(EID,EName,leaveType,StartDate,EndDate,Reason) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"); pst.setString(1, rs.getString(1)); pst.setString(2, rs.getString(2));
pst.setString(3, leaveType);
pst.setString(4, StartDate); pst.setString(5, EndDate);

Comment: pst.setString(6, reason);
            int row = pst.executeUpdate();                
            if(row==1)
            {
               %>
           <script>
            alert("Leave Applied");       
        </script>
        <jsp:include page="profile.jsp"></jsp:include> 
        <% 
            }            
}}
 catch(Exception e)
               {
                   out.println(e);
               }   
%>

Comment: For me the statement looks ok

Comment: Yes but it is still giving that error. Anyways again thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Check if there are not printable characters in this line

Comment: Okay I will check it

Comment: I understood now that why it was not accepting leave but want it be 'leave. In MySQL leave is reserved word. So maybe because of that I have use ' before leave.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not remamber this reserved word :D

Comment: I didn't knew too. I was watching random video on YouTube to create leave management system, there they was also using leave as table name but then they had error and solved by using ' and said that leave is reserved word in mysql.

Comment: it's mentioned here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L

Comment: Oh ok thanks for sending that link